# Including a database connection from a separate file

Tags: php, mysql, database

I currently have a db file I include to establish a DB connection:

db.php:

```
    $dbs = array(
    "127.0.0.1",
    "127.0.0.3",
    "127.0.0.2",
    );
if(!$con){
          $con = mysql_connect($dbs[rand(0,2)],"user_login","password") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());    
        }
```

However when I try to include it sometimes and do a query, it returns a blank result:

```
  include("db.php");
    mysql_select_db("database_table", $con);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where email='admin@test.com'");
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){$id =  $row['email'];break;}
```

The weird thing is, if I modify the initial db.php to connect like this, it works (non randomizing it):
db.php:

```
if(!$con){
          $con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","user_login","password") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());    
        }
```

Is there any explanation in this? Is there a difference in how they are connecting?

Thanks

Comment: why would you ever pick a random database

Comment: to randomly pick a node for the galera cluster

Comment: i can't imagine this is the approach galera recomends

Comment: Do all the databases have the same data?

Comment: yes they are all syncted accross

Answer (score 0):

First I would turn on error checking.

You can do that by adding the following to the very top of your php file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

or the long way by changing it globally: `display_errors = On` in your php.ini

This will output what's wrong. If you can't figure it out be then try the following:

---

Then check if you could connect to all databases like you did with

```
if(!$con){
      $con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","user_login","password") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());    
    }
```

Then I would check if they all had the same tables.

If that's correct I would check the output of your:

```
if(!$con){
      $con = mysql_connect($dbs[rand(0,2)],"user_login","password") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());    
    }
```

Does it really work the way it's intended?